# React Native error: "Can't find variable: TouchableHighlight"

Tags: react-native, expo, touchablehighlight

I'm trying to create a tic tac toe board in React Native using Expo.  I'm using TouchableHighlight to make the board touchable so that I can add X's and O's.  When the app is run I get the following error: 
"Can't find variable: TouchableHighlight" 
(Board.js 12:6).

Board.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class Board extends Component {

  _onPressButton() {
    console.log("you tapped the thing");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image source = {require('./board.png')} style = {styles.table}/>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}

const Xmark = (props) => (
  <View>
    <Image source = {require('./Xmark.png')} style = {styles.mark}/>
  </View>
);

const Omark = (props) => (
  <View>
    <Image source = {require('./Omark.png')} style = {styles.mark}/>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 6,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  table: {
    height: 250,
    width: 250,
  },
  mark: {
    height: 25,
    width: 25,
  },
});
```

Is there something else I need to import?  I looked at other people's code and I don't see anything significantly different.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to `import { TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native'`.

Comment: Thanks!  I figured it would be that simple.  Facebook should include this in their documentation.